# Creating threads from inside a worker thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, worker-thread

In my app, I need to make a number of TCP socket calls.

To be able to do this, I have to do the following steps: 
1. convert my data/command into a byte stream
2. create socket and send command and receive response
3. parse response and store for UI to use.

Now I have created a background thread to be able to do all three steps.

But in my socket client also I want to create a new thread for each new command (Step# 2)
So that would mean that I have a number of worker threads inside the common worker thread for all the three above steps.

So, would it be ok to use Async task for step #2 which is already taking place in a worker thread. Or do I use normal thread in this case.

One might wonder why am i not achieving all three steps in one worker thread. 
The point is that even if I create just one worker thread for all the socket commands, there is a possibility that the initial request for step 1 might itself come from a worker thread.

Hence, I cannot just assume that the call is from Main UI thread. 
Also, I wanted to ask whether it is not recommended to create your own worker threads in android and why?

Thanks, 
Sunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form your first 2 paragraphs i understand you want to establish some communication via sockets. i dont believe it would be a good approach to create a thread per command as thread itself and opening/closing sockets are expensive operations. 
i would suggest creating only one thread for opening and monitoring/writing/reading data to/from socket. if these commands are frequent than maintaining one socket alive is more appropriate than frequently opening/closing sockets. optionally i would create an extra thread for doing the extra work of serializing/deserializing commands (if they r time-consuming).

*One might wonder why am i not achieving all three steps in one worker thread. The point is that even if I create just one worker thread for all the socket commands, there is a possibility that the initial request for step 1 might itself come from a worker thread.*

I dont think it would make a big difference in your design approach where the requests come from.

*Hence, I cannot just assume that the call is from Main UI thread. Also, I wanted to ask whether it is not recommended to create your own worker threads in android and why?*

Android provides some very good generic classes such as AsyncTask and HandlerThread for general purpose usages but anyone is free to create a worker thread if the above ones do not fit the design requirements. Personally i create my own worker threads if i deal with socket programming.

I would suggest taking a look at Java NIO library specifically Selectors, and SocketChannel classes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AsyncTask for that.

AsyncTasks can only be [instantiated and executed on the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29).

You can, however, use standard threads.

class MyThread {

```
   @override
   public void run() {
          ......
          // when needed - span a new working thread fro within old one
          new MyOtherThread(...).start();  
   }
```

}

No problems here.

if you feel the number of threads you are spawning may go out of control, it is a smart idea to use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). The java.util.concurrent package has several, e.g.
ThreadPoolExecutor.

Finally, and I have give this recommendation several times before, if your task
is to transmit a large amount of small object using a multi threaded architecture, 
using [Volley](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) is probably the most effective way to go.

Good luck.